# Detecting disconnection of the client in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, client

When a client connection with the SQL Server (from **client side**) is cut, 
how can I detecting this disconnection in SQL Server (2008 or 2012)?

Can I solve this problem with **Server Triggers**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an [event notification](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186376.aspx) for the [Audit Logout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175827.aspx) event. The notification can launch an [activated procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Consider though that event notifications are asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

You could query one of the `sys` tables (`sysprocesses`)

```
SELECT 
   DB_NAME(dbid) AS Database, 
   loginame AS LoginName
FROM  sys.sysprocesses
```

You can also run the following stored procedure to see who is active:

```
 sp_who2
```

You would have to have a SQL Job or an active agent checking to see who has dropped out.

Comment: Database is a reserved word, you need to put brackets like: [Database]. Or else we get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Database'". I tried to edit your post, but my edit was rejected.

Comment: This does not work if you need to catch the 'event' before the user logs back in or the session ID is reused.