# Capture and react to a Session Close event in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, extended-events

I need a way to know when a session closes in SQL Server so I can clean up any resources allocated for that session by running a stored procedure I have.

When things are running perfectly, the client app would call a `Cleanup` routine to do this. But if the user gets disconnected unexpectedly, I need something on the server to know ... and call the cleanup.

Thinking in terms of languages like VB or Delphi, I would register an event handler for this.

I see that SQL Server has 'Extended Events' but I have not figured out how to react to those events in a stored procedure or trigger...

Or is there some other way to capture a `SessionClose` and then call a stored procedure?

Comment: Does the cleanup have to run immediately? If not a scheduled cleanup, that clears up stuff once an hour, or daily might do the trick.

Comment: Not a bad idea @Mirronelli.
My resources are based on the SessionId.
So my concern is to have things cleaned up before another process gets that same ID again.  Otherwise, the existing StoredProcedure would associate the old data with this new process.

Comment: Do you have the option of making your resource reliant on something other than session id? For example, before VB runs a task, it puts an entry in the DB with a GUID with a start date and NULL end date. Your resources could tie to that GUID. If something goes wrong and end date for that GUID is not populated by 24h, a process could clean up the resources.

Comment: You are on to something @zedfoxus.   
The Session ID is required.     
But I can make a unique index on SessionID | GUID.     
So if I see the same SessionID come in with a different guid, I can assume the old one is dead and run cleanup.     

Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Once you try out a solution like that, add your own answer below and then mark your own answer as accepted, if possible. That’ll give closure to your question and others with similar issue can find value from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet !

From here : [Detecting disconnection of the client in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168720/detecting-disconnection-of-the-client-in-sql-server)

> You can create an [event notification](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186376.aspx) for the [Audit Logout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175827.aspx) event. The notification can launch an [activated procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Consider though that event notifications are asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this with an `Init` | `Deinit` type of function.

I am using Native-Complied Stored Procedures which are limited in what information they can obtain.  So the Init works out well -- the client (or wrapper SP) can get the info needed, pass to Init, and it stores that off to a session table.

The client calls `Init` before it does anything else.  If there are resources associated with this session, it is assumed the first user has died and the previous resources released.

Extremely simplified Pseudo code:

```
function Init(info . . .)
begin
     if ( isSessionActive(@@spid) )
          releaseSession(@@spid)
     newSession(@@spid)
end
```

```
function Deinit()
begin
     releaseSession(@@spid)
end
```

```
native-compiled procedure doSomething()
begin
     getResources(@@spid, . . . .)
end
```